# how to force Android Studio 0.6.0 to use SDK Build Tools 19.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just updated my Android Studio to 0.6.0 and updated the SDK Build Tools to 19.1.0 however I got this error:

```
The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low. Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

How do I force it to use SDK Build Tools 19.1.0?  I tried removing 19.0.3 but it doesn't help.

```
[  75364]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low. Minimum required is 19.1.0 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low. Minimum required is 19.1.0
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:352)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:334)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:364)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:330)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)

[  75373]   WARN - .project.GradleProjectImporter -
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can edit build.gradle file:

```
android {

      compileSdkVersion 19
      buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"





    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Note that: build.gradle is in the same folder as the build and src folder.

```
ProjectFolder --> AppFolder --> build.gradle
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks mate! i came from eclipse and just getting my hands on android studio.

Comment: Make sure you do this for all libraries you are compiling as well.

Comment: Why would I want to edit the build.gradle file if the issue is clearly an overlooked update. Not a good idea in my view. I much prefer Dmitry's solution (the one with screenshots in this thread).

Comment: @NightKnight Dimitry's answer edits the same file in step 5. he just does it through the GUI.

Comment: @NightKnight i appreciate Dmitry's answer but i prefer to know behind the scenes

Comment: @MartinKonecny your comment was saved my day... Why don't you put your comment within the answer.

Answer (score 72):

Or through ui interface Android studio

1. Open SDK Manager 
   [image]
2. Select SDK Build tools you needs
   [image]
3. After complete install open settings your module
   [image]
4. In properties in modules select SDK Build tools
   [image]
5. If you have submodules do these steps for all modules
   [image]

Comment: So simple solution but I wasted so much time on it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you imported any library, you need to change the build.gradle file for each library, if they are in a different directory

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for "buildToolsVersion" all over my build.gradle, but not within the dependencies! Your suggestion solved my issue!